# Apache Solr: Removing Stopwords from LukeRequestHandler's topTerms

Tags: solr, stop-words

title pretty much says everything, I'm querying Solr for its topTerms using the LukeRequestHandler, is but the list contains lots of short words like 'is', 'a', 'do' (actually, they're german) and so on...

These are actually all in my stopwords file, is there a way to stop Solr from listing them as topTerms?

**EDIT:** Hm, is it possible that I made a mistake configuring my stopwords? Searching for stopwords still gives me results...

thx for any help